# Kubeflow Multiple images components in pipeline

Tags: kubeflow, kfp

I want to write a pipeline in Kubeflow pipeline that has 2 components: A and B

The output of A is list of image path.

I want to run a docker image (B) for each image path

From what I see the `dsl.ContainerOp` of B can wait for output of A, but I don't know how to create multiple instances of B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: This has changed recently and can be done simply by using `ParallerlFor` over the output. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59292863/4438213

----- Below for KF 0.6 and before ----

This is a recognized issue with Kubeflow DSL: *to use the output of one component (A) and iterate over it running a new component (B) for each entry in the previous output*. It's hard since the DSL, Kubeflow uses, is at compile time and it's not possible to know how many elements there would be in the output at that time.

Ref:

- https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/1967
- https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/1481

The only form of dynamic (run-time) iteration supported as of KF v0.6 is: [dsl-recursion](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/sdk/dsl-recursion/). I've made it work in 2 ways lacking the pending work on the issues above:

If the size of the result of A is going to be a constant in each run and is pre-known, this is straight forward.

**CASE A: The size of the output from the previous step is known**

1. Create a lightweight comp to get the image path at a given index

```
# Write a python code to extract the path from
# the string of refs the previous step returns 
def get_path(str_of_paths: str, idx: int) -> str:
    return str_of_paths.split(" ")[idx] # or some other delimiter
```

2. Wrap the python code in a [Kubeflow lightweight components](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/sdk/lightweight-python-components/)

```
get_img_path_comp = comp.func_to_container_op(get_path,base_image='tensorflow/tensorflow') # or any appropriate base image
```

And then a regular for loop in your pipeline dsl code would work

```
image_path_res = ContainerOP_A() # run your container Op
for idx in range(4):
    path = get_path(image_path_res.output, i)
    ContainerOp_B(path.output)
```

**CASE B: When the output of the previous step is not of fixed size**

This is a little tricky and intricate. The only form of dynamic looping Kubeflow allows as of KF v0.6 is [dsl-recursion](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/sdk/dsl-recursion/)

***Option 1***

1. Create 2 lightweight components, one for calculating the size of the result `sizer_op` and then reuse the same `get_img_path_comp` from above.

```
@dsl.component
def sizer_op(str_of_refs) -> int:
    return len(str_of_refs.split("|"))
sizer_op_comp = comp.func_to_container_op(sizer_op,base_image='tensorflow/tensorflow')
```

Then you can run the recusive function

```
@dsl.component
def subtracter_op(cur_idx) -> int:
    return cur_idx - 1
sub_op_comp = comp.func_to_container_op(subtracter_op,base_image='tensorflow/tensorflow')

@dsl.graph_component
def recursive_run(list_of_images, cur_ref):
    with dsl.Condition(cur_ref >= 0):
        path = get_path(image_path_res.output, i)
        ContainerOp_B(path.output)

        # call recursively
        next_ref = sub_op_comp(cur_ref)
        recursive_run(list_of_images, next_ref)


image_path_res = ContainerOP_A() # run your container Op
sizer = sizer_op_comp(image_path_res)
recursive_run(image_path_res.output, sizer.output)
```

***Option 2***

After running ContainerOp_A, create a Kubeflow Component that reads the results from ContainerOp_A, parses the results in python code itself and then spawns new runs that run just Containerop_B using kfclient. You can connect to KF pipeline client using:

```
kf_client = Client(host=localhost:9990)
```

Refer: [kf_client](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/sdk/python/kfp/_client.py)

Comment: `cur_ref - 1`. You cannot do this. There is no agent that will be able to execute that subtraction at runtime. You should get a compile error that you cannot do `PipelineParam - 1`

Comment: Thanks for catching that @Ark-kun! I forgot to mention I use a Python Lightweight component for this. Also updated the answer for latest KFP versions that can do this with `ParallelFor`