# kubeflow ParallelFor using the previous containerop output

Tags: python, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I can create a static for loop using

```
with dsl.ParallelFor([1,2,3]) as item:
   ....
```

How can I use a `container_op.output` as an input to `ParallelFor`?
Assume the first container outputs an integer `n`, and then I want to run `ParallelFor` n times.

Attempts like this does not work:

```
container_op = ContainerOp(...)
with dsl.ParallelFor(container_op.output) as item:
   ....
```

I'm trying to stimulate a parallel python `range(n)` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change to suport `withItem`(static looping) and `withParams` (dynamic looping) was done in multiple parts, but they're all available now. Refer [PR](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/pull/2044).

Ensure that your KPF version is `0.1.31` or above.

It's possible to loop over the output of a previous `container_op` as below

```
echo_op = dsl.ContainerOp(
        name='echo',
        image='library/bash:4.4.23',
        command=['sh', '-c'],
        arguments=['echo "[1,2,3]"> /tmp/output.txt'],
        file_outputs={'output': '/tmp/output.txt'})

with dsl.ParallelFor(echo_op.output) as item:
        iterate_op = dsl.ContainerOp(
        name='iterate',
        image='library/bash:4.4.23',
        command=['sh', '-c'],
        arguments=[f"echo {item} > /tmp/output.txt"],
        file_outputs={'output': '/tmp/output.txt'})
```

Ensure that your output YAML looks something like this:

```
        name: for-loop-for-loop-3c29048d-1
        template: for-loop-for-loop-3c29048d-1
        withParam: '{{tasks.echo.outputs.parameters.echo-output}}'
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to zip two outputs in `ParallelFor` and feed them for the second component?